# Does CancellationToken removes file lock?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, cancellation-token

I have following async function:

```
private async Task<bool> ValidateFtpAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(
            () =>
            {
                if(File.Exists("settings.xml"))
                {
                    var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Information));
                    using (var read = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        Information info = (Information)xs.Deserialize(read);

                        try
                        {
                            var DecryptedInfo = FileCryptoDecryptor.ReadEncryptedConfiguration("hakuna.xml.aes", Global_Variables.AppPassword);
                            string DecryptedFTPPass = EncryDecryptor.Decrypt(DecryptedInfo.FtpPassword, "UltraSecretPasswordNotGonnaSayItToYou");
                            return General_Functions.isValidConnection(info.HDSynologyIP, info.FtpUsername, DecryptedFTPPass);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Missing settings file.");
                    return false;
                }

            });
    }
```

You can see it reads data from a file. My question is if i use CancellationToken for async method does it remove file lock when its in using block?

Comment: it should I think because the using block will go out of scope.

Comment: BTW, 1) you shouldn't use `Task.Run` for I/O-bound tasks, it is somewhat a waste of a thread 2) You shouldn't perform GUI operations (`MessageBox`) inside a child thread even if the operation uses its own message pump

Comment: When you use Cancel from the token source your `Task` would throw a `TaskCancelledException` thus  all resources held would get released , including your lock on the file.

Comment: @MickyD I have it for loading animations. Its decrypting file and its taking a while so i do it async so i dont block gui and can show loading animation. Didnt found better solution but still beginner and my first project so still learning.

Comment: TPL DataFlow would be a better choice.  You still shouldn't rely on UI operations working in a thread pool thread

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Not a problem good sir, I should have mentioned it in my first comment :)

Comment: The lock will be removed, but not as a direct effect of the `CancellationToken`. The only responsibility the `CancellationToken` has is to throw an `OperationCanceledException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, cancellation token by itself does not do anything (and in particular does not close files). The task's code needs to check state of the token repeatedly and act accordingly to perform cancellation.

It is unclear where do you plan to use a cancellation token in your case as there is no repeated operations... But since code has properly set with `using(…){}` statements irrespective where you break the operation the file will be correctly closed in `finally` block of `using (var read = new FileStream(...`.